# Keyboard does not appear for EditText in View

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My application has started to behave strangely, so I think there must have been a change that I am not grasping.  I have an EditText in a RelativeLayout with a requestFocus attribute.  For months I would open my app and execute an initialize method and then touch the edit text and the keyboard would appear.  Now the keyboard does not appear.  I have tried to set an onClick Listener and onFocusChange with the InputMethodManager using:

```
m.showSoftInput(amountEditText, 0);
```

and also with

```
m.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Since this is new, unexpected behavior, I am afraid that there was something I changed that caused this odd behavior.  I have looked at the XML and the WYSIWYG for the view and cannot see anything wrong.  The SO answers all seem to have much more complex situations that this so I think something more basic is at fault.  Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static void showSoftkeyboard(android.view.View view, ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {
    Configuration config = view.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    if (config.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (resultReceiver != null) {
            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, resultReceiver);
        } else {
            imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, check your AndroidManifest.xml if you didn't disable the softKeyboard for your Activity.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.  I added the method, without the ResultReceiver in an onClick listener.  I have tried it. The edit text receives the focus, and the soft keyboard appears.  I  am not at all clear why this was required, but I will certainly accept the answer, thnx.

Comment: The `resultReceiver` is optional

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I was facing a similar problem. One way to force the keyboard to be shown is this way:

```
    //here my EditText is called editText_search
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(editText_search.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

    editText_search.requestFocus();
```

Also, as Simon Marquis pointed out, see if you're blocking or hiding the keyboard in your Manifest.

Hope it helps.